# Переопределение статической переменной

Tags: c#, ооп, наследование, полиморфизм, статические-члены

Как можно переопределить статическую переменную родительского класса?

```
    class A{  
        static int x;  
        int y {get;set;}  

        public A(int k){  
            y = f(k);  
        }

        public int f(int k){return k*x;}

    }
    class B:A{  
        x = 7 //я хочу переопределить статическую переменную класса A. Но я не знаю как
        public B(int k):base(int k){}
    }
```

Я хочу что бы было :

```
B b = new B(3);
Console.WriteLine(b.y); // вывелось число 21;
```

То есть, когда создавался объект B, и началось присваивание `y = f(3)`,  в методе `f()` эта тройка была умножена на семерку(т.е на переопределённую статическую `x`).

Comment: емнип, переопределить можно только виртуальные члены, а члены не могут быть и виртуальными и статическими одновременно

Comment: Вот именно [static](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35203028/5752652) и [const](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23987101/5752652) переопределить нельзя, но вы можете скрывать за new и делать override и этого вполне достаточно на практике.

Comment: Можете  пожалуйста приложить код?

Answer (score 2):

Задание значения полю перенесите в конструктор:

```
public B(int k) : base(k)
{
    x = 7;
}
```

Само поле объявите с модификатором

```
protected static int x;
```

После этого код будет работать.

---

Зачем это нужно, хорошо это или плохо - оставим в стороне.

Comment: При вызове `base(k)` мы перейдём сразу же в конструктор родительского класса, и значение x не переопределится. А поле `у` ,будет равно `k*0`, а не `k*7`

Comment: @Good_Sasha - добавьте в конструктор класса `B` строчку: `y = f(k);`. И будет вам 21 в итоге.